# Need some pointers on Vowpal Wabbit with respect to cross validation

Tags: vowpalwabbit

My goal is to do a grid search over various VW models in their parameter space (trying different loss functions and regularizations etc). Since the model could use multiple passes, I would like to use cross validation. I am wondering if I should implement my own cross validation code (perhaps as a bash script) or am I reinventing the wheel. Any pointers on whether this has been done before etc or best ways to proceed would be useful. I was looking at implementing cross validation in a bash script and using GNU parallel to parallelize the Grid Search

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should try the vw-hypersearch perl script ( https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/blob/HEAD/utl/vw-hypersearch ) which can also be found in the utl directory of VW. It can help you tune the VW parameters, but as for as cross-validation you have to implement your own code, feeding the algorithm with the data folds you intend to validate.

Comment: I'm guessing this page didn't exist when LucaM gave his answer, but the following link has some good instructions: https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Using-vw-hypersearch

Answer (score 1):

Allow me to answer this question in 2 folds,

- Cross Validation: There is no flag for the same in vw. The reason
  being that even post cross validation, one would test on a future
  split and evaluate the learning of the model based on some metric
  derived from the Confusion Matrix.
- Hyper-parameter Search: the vw-hypersearch uses golden ration search to search 
  for an optimal value of a given parameter when the range is provided. Golden 
  Ratio Search works for a function which is
  monotonically increasing or decreasing. When doing a search over a
  bunch of parameters the function is no longer a monotonically
  increasing or decreasing function. This can be handled using as you
  had pointed out

  -- Grid Search: very CPU intensive and time consuming.(we always fight
  with time)

  -- Random Search: Very efficient Reference:
  [http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2188395][1]